# SharePoint Taxonomy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, taxonomy

We wanted to use taxonomy in our Environment and i had imported a term set using an .csv file and it worked fine , now  I was wondering is there a way that i can use the same .csv to import the text in Spanish also so that the text will change automatically when some once changed from english to Spanish .

I don't want to change the text using translator as we have like 1000 Terms in the term set ..

Comment: I tried to change the LCID to 3082 but its creating a new term set is there a way that i can achieve that without it creating a new term set.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read through the TechNet documentation on Multi Lingual Term Sets?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678224.aspx

If so, what issues have you come across?

Comment: Hi James I as i mentioned before i am adding the term sets through a .csv file and there  if i have some term called "Agriculture" , i want to display the same term in Spanish so  i changed the LCID to 3082 but its showing as  a new term instead of changing depending on lauangauge